Definition of topological quotient
I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.
By definition, a continuous map (between topological spaces) is said to be a quotient map if it is surjective and the codomain is endowed with the finest topology among those that make the map continuous from the topology on the domain. Furthermore, a topological space is said to be a quotient of another if there exists a quotient map from the latter to the former.
My question is basically to provide evidence for the plausibility of this (formally unquestionable) definition. I am used to think of quotient as images (as e.g. in set theory), so I can't see the point in restricting the definition of quotients of a space only to those arising from images of quotient maps (and not, say, consider all images of continuous maps from it). Is there an intrinsic reason? or maybe there is no actual loss of generality? I'd like some more experienced topologist to enlighten this situation not having the topological or category-theoretical background to do it by myself.

The first point to note is that there are "enough quotients:" Given a space $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on it, there is a quotient space $X / {{\sim}}$ of $X$ whose set of points is the corresponding quotient of sets. The reason we need to talk about something like quotient maps is that we have certain requirements on the topology of that space: Any continuous function $f\colon X \to Y$ that respects $\sim$ should factor over $X / {{\sim}}$, i.e. there is a continuous map $f'\colon X / {{\sim}} \to Y$ such that $f = f' \circ p$ ($p$ the quotient projection).

If you define $X$ to be a quotient of $Y$ whenever there is a continuous surjection $Y \to X$, then you get statements like "$\mathbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology," which is very much not what you want: There are no interesting maps out of an indescrete space.

First of all quotient spaces actually arise as quotients. Meaning given $X$ and equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ we first form the quotient set $X/\sim$ with projection $\pi:X\to X/\sim$. We then give topology on the quotient: $U\subseteq X/\sim$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. This is the true motivation behind quotient spaces. Because we are often interested in equivalence relations, which is more than just an image of some function as we will see soon.
The two definitions are the same. In the following sense: if $f:X\to Y$ then we can define $x \sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$. It turns out that if $f$ is a quotient map, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X/\sim$. And on the other hand $\pi$ is a quotient map almost by definition.
Now those assumptions are essential. Indeed, one can show that a quotient of a discrete space is always discrete. However every topological space $X$ is a continuous image of some discrete space. One such example is the identity $X\to X$ with discrete topology on the left side.
And so in the topological context looking at image only is not enough. And unlike sets (and other categories like groups) the concept of image and quotient are distinct in topology.
And quotients not only behave a lot better than images, but also often arise naturally when doing topology.
